# Cube.js is throwing an error when trying to connect to Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cube.js

I am trying to build a Dashboard using cube.js and MongoDb.But i am trying to access a schema getting error

````
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/Users/test/mongo-tutorial/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:171:17) at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11) at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5) at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5) at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10```

Does anyone know what is causing this error?
````

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times it means incorrect `CUBEJS_DB_HOST` and/or `CUBEJS_DB_PORT` env variables are set.